# Is it safe to delete Populations in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder, contact-deletion, populations

We are working on a Contact Deletion process in SFMC and are now dealing with an issue regarding Populations. Basically it's not removing contacts from there and so they still count against the billing limit.

I have read contrasting posts here on StackExchange, does anyone know the latest on this? We prefer to just delete the Populations but are unsure if it might break our journeys.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

Journey Builder doesn't require the use of a population with most entry events. If you are using the [older legacy entry event](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_entry_events.htm&type=5), you will still need to use a population or ensure all contacts exist in the "All subscriber" list before injecting it into a journey.

You can also use the population as the source of email address in journey settings, So if you inject a new subscriber this population could be the source of an email address needed to do an email send

Populations can also be leveraged in entry filters or decision splits.

However, no one can advise you if you are able to delete a population with no adverse effects, simply because you will need to review your journeys to ensure a population isn't being leveraged for the above use cases.